# How to use knife-essentials to backup Chef 11

Tags: backup, chef-infra, knife

I'm trying to use knife-essentials to backup all objects in a Chef 11 server to json files. I created a directory "backup" containing .chef/download.rb

```
transfer_repo = File.expand_path('..', File.dirname(__FILE__))
chef_server_url "https://localhost"
node_name 'chef-importer'
client_key "~/.chef/client.pem"
repo_mode 'everything'
versioned_cookbooks true
chef_repo_path transfer_repo
cookbook_path nil
```

When I try to use "knife download" I get this error:

```
# /usr/local/rvm/bin/chef_knife download -c .chef/download.rb /
ERROR: TypeError: can't convert nil into String
```

This is complaining about cookbook_path, so I tried removing that line, but that gives me this:

```
ERROR: File chef is a directory while file chef is a regular file
```

What's the correct way to use knife-essentials to download everything in Chef 11?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your Ruby version. I would recommend using RVM and ruby version 1.9.2.
This should help you.